# Is there any way to create admin panel in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I want to create a mobile app in react native with firebase backend. Data should be added from admin panel(in react) and only authenticated users will see that data.how i can achieve that.

Note : - both react native and react app should use same firebase project

Comment: This question is probably too broad for SO. It sounds like you might want to use some combination of Firebase services like Cloud Firestore for your database and Firebase Authentication to manage authenticated requests. There are loads of tutorials for things like this. You should start by checking out the Firebase docs. https://firebase.google.com/docs

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This community wants to help you, but will not deliver code based on a few sentences and a technology list. In order to get a good answer, please read [ask] and provide an example of whet you have tried ([mcve]), and a clear description of what you want solved.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The thing is i want to add two different project one is react and another is react native in same firebase project. Admin panel is in react to add data and mobile app in react native to display data to users

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible you need to use Firebase auth, Firestore, and any other components you want like media just make sure to make all components public false so anyone can not edit anything.
Then config React-Native and React-Js firebase with the same project. 
after that anything you'll from react-js and it'll be shown in React-Native mobile project.

Comment: How can i make components to false

Comment: Check out the [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qyK3QS1DU8N3bQbtM9efYfdkn7j8nAr2/view?usp=sharing)